# How to fix internal and external links after migrating WordPress sites

Tags: database, wordpress, migration, broken-links

### Short version

I recently migrated my two sites, two of were a WordPress platform, we combined two of them into one site due to security reasons. However, after the migration, all the internal and external links on the site (posts) were generated with the addition of " and / before and after each link and even for the images. I have tried using the "Better Search and Replace" plugin, but it only worked for a few cases and is not effective any more.

I also tried updating the URL in the wp posts table, but that did not work either. The only solution I have found so far is to clean up the posts manually, which is a time-consuming task. Unfortunately, we are also experiencing a lot of 404 not found errors, and they appear in the report as follows: "https://example.com/blog/party-bus/"https:/example.com/prom-limo/".

### More detailed version

The user had two websites, one main site and another WordPress site located in a different folder called "Blog". However, due to security concerns, they were advised to merge the two sites into one. After the migration process was completed, all internal and external links were generated with additional backslashes and quotes, such as " and /, appearing before and after each link, example "https://example.com/airport-transfers-new-york/". This caused many broken links and 404 errors to appear on their website.

To try and fix the issue, the user attempted to use a "Better Search and Replace" plugin. However, this only worked for some of the links, and was not effective in solving the problem. The user then tried to update the URL in the posts table, but this also did not produce any positive results.

The user now finds themselves in a situation where they have many 404 not found errors, and links that appear in the reports with additional backslashes and quotes. This is causing a significant amount of frustration, and is affecting the user's ability to maintain their website.

The user is seeking advice and guidance on what steps they should take to resolve the issue and ensure that their website is functioning properly. They are hoping for a solution that will not require them to spend a lot of time manually cleaning up the posts.

I utilized the better search and replace plugin, as well as manually edited the database to eliminate the unnecessary forward slashes in the links. My expectation is to receive additional suggestions or techniques for effectively resolving the issue of broken links in the database.

Comment: Can you get a copy of the database, and work on it locally on a development machine? I would look at scanning the wp_posts table with a script, working out if it needs fixing automatically (e.g. using curl) and then applying a fix using the same script. Are you comfortable writing PHP from scratch? If so, you can work on a local database, and then upload that table when you are happy that your auto-fix approach is reliable.